# Make object from a child

Tags: objects, edit-mode

I would like to make object from a child so i can edit it, there is a way to do this?
I use the Duplication to a sphere from a plane, i want to make object from the result (the new sphere created).

sorry for my english i will put a screenshot for help, i read i have to select the parent and do ***Shift + Ctrl + A***     but its not working.[image]
Thanks :)

Comment: Fredo, it is unclear to me what you are asking. The confusing part for me, is that you want to make an "object from a child". But the way the word "child" is used in Blender, it refers to entities that are already a separate, editable objects from their parents. And "duplication" is not the word used for the process of making one object the child of another; the word for that is "parenting". I intended to vote to close the question as too vague, but perhaps you can clarify what you want to do, perhaps with the use of a screenshot or two, and a copy of the blend file.

Comment: My english isnt my langage i hope with the screenshot its more clear....

Comment: Fred, the screenshot helps a little, but unfortunately, not enough.

Comment: Ok then delete the question i will make new one and try to be more clear

Comment: Fred, only you, or moderators, can delete the question. I'm not a moderator so I can't delete it. I already understood from reading your question that English wasn't your strongest language, but maybe an onlne search might turn up something like Stack Exchange in your primary language.

Comment: @Fredo, I think I might understand.  Did you use the _Duplication_ settings to put the plane on each face of the sphere?  And now you want to make all of the planes "real" so you can edit them as one object?

Comment: Yes i did it!  It was simple i just needed to do Shift+Ctrl+A just after the duplication.... and i have all my planes as one object so i can work on it!   Thanks

Comment: @Fredo8454, congratulations!  Please add your solution as an "Answer" below so this won't show up as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i did it! It was simple i just needed to do Shift+Ctrl+A just after the duplication.... and i have all my planes as one object so i can work on it! Thanks